# PostgreSQL. Обратиться к таблице не зная ее имени напрямую

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица **TABLE1**, в колонке которой хранятся названия других таблиц. Есть ли возможность в ***postgreSQL*** получить содержимое этих самых таблиц не обращаясь к ним напрямую вбивая ***название руками***, а ***выдергивая их из*** **TABLE1**?

В нете не смог найти ничего подобного. Заранее спасибо)

Чуть подробнее:
TABLE1 содержит сотни записей. Каждая запись имеет имя таблицы, к которой она относится. Таблиц гораздо меньше и их имена мы получаем при помощи запроса:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLENAME FROM TABLE1;
```

В результате получаем таблицу, в каждой строчке которой лежит имя таблицы.
После этого, мне нужно создать таблицу, которая бы в 1-ом столбце писала имя таблицы из TABLE1, а во 2-ом количество записей в этой таблице.

Comment: [Динамический SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html).

Comment: на практике такое желание почти наверняка свидетельствует о неправильной структуре БД...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно генерировать произвольный запрос в текстовом виде и получать содержимое любой таблицы. Вопрос только, какой запрос в итоге должен получиться. Динамический запрос можно выполнить так:

Есть такие операторы: - [PREPARE](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/sql-prepare), [EXECUTE](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/sql-execute) и [execute из PL/pgSQL](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-statements).

```
-- Собираешь произвольный запрос в текстовой форме
-- Добавляешь к нему 'PREPARE my_plan AS ', где my_plan - имя запроса
-- Запускаешь подготовленную команду через процедурный execute
-- В конце, запускаешь EXECUTE с указанным ранее именем запроса 


DO $$
DECLARE _sql varchar;
BEGIN -- Тут опиши свой запрос
    _sql = COALESCE((SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT
                             'SELECT
                                '||quote_literal(TABLENAME)||' AS name
                                , (SELECT count(*) FROM '||quote_ident(TABLENAME)||') AS countt'                                  
                             ,' UNION ') 
                     FROM TABLE1
                     ),'SELECT '||quote_literal('Нет данных')||' AS name, 0 AS countt'); 
    _sql = 'PREPARE my_plan AS ' || _sql;

    BEGIN
        execute _sql;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUPLICATE_PREPARED_STATEMENT THEN 
            _sql='DEALLOCATE my_plan; '||_sql;
            execute _sql;
    END;

END $$;

EXECUTE my_plan;
```

Код DO $$ ... END $$ можно обернуть в хранимую процедуру, в которую передавать сгенерированный запрос в виде параметра и вызывать его для каждой таблицы из **TABLE1**.

Comment: Благодарю. Пока не могу точно сказать, то ли это решение, которое мне нужно, потому как не шарю в sql настолько, чтобы быстро понять, как это все работает.

Comment: Чтобы дать полное решение, нужен пример результата, который необходимо получить

Comment: Чуть подробнее расписал вопрос, надеюсь это как-то прояснит ситуацию. Основной проблемой для меня осталось обработка и понимание типов возвращаемых при тех или иных запросах. Как можно последовательно передавать имена таблиц в ф-цию, и как обрабатывать результаты запроса SELECT. Какой тип данных получаем на выходе (какой тип данных OUT нужно задать ф-ции).

Comment: дополнил подсчетом количества записей, если не ошипся с кафычками, заработает...

Comment: Чрезвычайно благодарен, все сработало. Теперь осталось разбираться как это все работает и что здесь что. Еще раз спасибо.